# How do I append jQuery in EJS?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, ejs

This has been a major downer for me. Can't I run jQuery natively inside EJS?

I've been reading a lot on this but can't find the resources that really help. Let's say I just want to log from the EJS template using jQuery, how would I achieve this?

Say we have this snippet:

```
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

</script>
```

I've put this in my footer.ejs file which I'm including using EJS tags. But it doesn't log at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install jQuery with node, it's because you want to use jQuery on the server side of your application so you will be mostly using it for server side functionality, probably more of the core methods, obviously not anything dom related.

For using jQuery on the client, you still need to add jQuery to your page, either using a static reference, or possibly install it with bower and inclue it from your bower_components folder

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can use browserify to bundle your client side includes into a bundle file e.g. main.js or bundle.js

```
<script src="js/bundle.min.js"></script>
```

If you are using Jade, you can add the script tag to your template